# Thymeleaf title attibute with html tags

Tags: java, jquery, html, thymeleaf

Actually I'm using summernote https://summernote.org/ plugin to style the text and saved it into database. It gives the string as `<b style='color:#CCC'>Test</b>`.
In normal text cases i'm using **th:utext** attribute. But i doesn't make this available for **th:title**. How to do this in thymeleaf ? Thanks in advance

1. In first scenario, i want to show it as text, So i used this implementation `<span th:utext="${text}"></span>` and this is working as expected
2. In second scenario, i want to show it as title for other tag like
   `<a th:title="${text}">Some other text </a>` this gives title with tag as a string.Not applying styles to title. How can i get these title with text style provided by string

   In both cases `${text}` is `<b style='color:#CCC'>Test</b>`. How can i get unescaped text in title attribute.

Comment: You mean you are doing something like this? `<th:block th:utext="<b th:title='some title' style='color:#CCC'>Test</b>"></th:block>`

Comment: No i'm doing for normal text like '<span th:utext="<b style='color:#CCC'>"></span>' but for other tag i need to show it as title. like '<a title="<b style='color:#CCC'>">Text</a>'

Comment: Do you have to use `<b style='color:#CCC'>` for `th:utext`? Why not just put it inside `span` tag?

Comment: That's the string which is coming from the server i just placed it into the other tag for getting other text too. But that's not my problem. I have a problem with title attribute. can you help me there?

Comment: Can you describe your result of 2nd one?

Comment: @user2652379 i updated my question. Please go through it and help me. thanks

Comment: You can't style title attribute in tags. Is title you are mentioning is `Some other text`?

Comment: Please write the final result that you exactly want

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting `<b style='color:#CCC'>Test</b>` string using model (like `th:utext="${text}"`),  try like this:

- From server: `model.addAttribute("text", "<b style='color:#CCC'>Test</b>");`
- Html #1: `<span th:utext="${text}"></span>`
- Html #2: `<a th:title="${text}">Some other text </a>`

I tried on my server and worked.

Comment: I didn't see the second one. Will try it

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But i am very comfortable with first scenario. In fact everything is working fine my end. I want to get second scenario only.

Comment: @Confuser I added 2nd answer